# MS Graph API v1.0 cannot filter by onPremisesSamAccountName using Python requests

Tags: python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to use Python + requests to talk with MS Graph API (v1.0) in order to filter user objects by the **onPremisesSamAccountName** property but am receiving this error when sending the simple query:

```
endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

query_parameters = {
    '$filter': 'onPremisesSamAccountName eq \'somevalue\'',
    '$select': 'id,displayName,mail,onPremisesSamAccountName'
}

user_graph_data = requests.get(
    endpoint,
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
    params=query_parameters
).json()
```

==============================

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'onPremisesSamAccountName' of resource 'User'.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "...",
      "request-id": "...",
      "client-request-id": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to filter using this field while using Microsoft's Graph Explorer:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and the corresponding Javascript call in the developer console shows a successful call and response based on the filter with **onPremisesSamAccountName**.

The MS Graph docs for v1.0 state that this is a supported field for filtering as well:

> Returned only on $select. Supports $filter (eq, ne, NOT, ge, le, in,
> startsWith).

I'm also able to successfully filter using other fields such as 'mail' (i.e. changing the $filter string from `'onPremisesSamAccountName eq \'somevalue\'' to 'mail eq \'somevalue\''` works just fine, so I don't believe this is a syntactical error)

Comment: On my end onPremisesSamAccountName  returns the same error on both Graph Explorer. Also I don't have users synced from onprem. If the query works for you on Graph Explorer then you would ensure the puthon script is not sending any invalid characters and compare the permissions added on GE and those added to access token.

Comment: From what I can tell there shouldn't be any invalid characters since simply swapping the filter string from 'mail' to 'onPremisesSamAccountName' is the only thing I am changing that causes a successful query to become an unsuccessful query. The AAD application should also have sufficient permissions.